# Trying to get property of non-object (show.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have this problem in my routes where in I get this error tying to get property of non-object view **(show.blade.php)** on clicking a link to view/redirect **allstats.blade.php**. It is very weird because I am not returning my routes to show.blade.php but to allstats.blade.php. I was wondering if I am doing something wrong with the routes. This is very tricky, I don't know what's causing this error.

@Controller:

**EmployeeController.php**

```
    public function postdisplaySummaryReport()
{
    $employeesquery = Employee::paginate(10);

    return View::make('employees.allstats')
    ->with('employeequerytoallstat', $employeesquery);
}
```

@Routes:

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('employees/sumarryReports','EmployeeController@postdisplaySummaryReport');
Route::resource('employees', 'EmployeeController');
```

@**index.php**(URL to the allstat.blade.php):

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('employees/sumarryReports') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span> {{trans('labels.payroll_reports.lbl_summary_report')}}</a>
```

@ERROR:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change your function to this.

```
 public function postdisplaySummaryReport()
 {
    $employeesquery = Employee::paginate(10);

    return view('employees.allstats')
    ->with('employeequerytoallstat', $employeesquery);
}
```

also change your Route method to get instead of post if you want to display content.

```
Route::get('employees/sumarryReports','EmployeeController@postdisplaySummaryReport');
```